# Understanding Digital IMU 6DOF sketch

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors

I am looking at the following code and getting confused by a few elements in it:

1) Why is there a writeto function being performed to the memory locations x053,0x31,x09 for accelerometer and 0x68,0x16 and 0x1A for gyro? We are only reading incoming values so what is the purpose of these functions?

2) the bitwise operation being performed in the getGyrscopeReadings and getAccelerometerReadings... are these operations to define how many bits data we will be reading?

```
    #include <Wire.h> //The I2C library

int gyroResult[3], accelResult[3];

//Function for writing a byte to an address on an I2C device
void writeTo(byte device, byte toAddress, byte val) {
  Wire.beginTransmission(device);  
  Wire.write(toAddress);        
  Wire.write(val);        
  Wire.endTransmission();
}

//Function for reading num bytes from addresses on an I2C device
void readFrom(byte device, byte fromAddress, int num, byte result[]) {
  Wire.beginTransmission(device);
  Wire.write(fromAddress);
  Wire.endTransmission();
  Wire.requestFrom((int)device, num);
  int i = 0;
  while(Wire.available()) {
    result[i] = Wire.read();
    i++;
  }
}

//Function for reading the gyros.
void getGyroscopeReadings(int gyroResult[]) {
  byte buffer[6];
  readFrom(0x68,0x1D,6,buffer);
  gyroResult[0] = (((int)buffer[0]) << 8 ) | buffer[1]; //Combine two bytes into one int
  gyroResult[1] = (((int)buffer[2]) << 8 ) | buffer[3];
  gyroResult[2] = (((int)buffer[4]) << 8 ) | buffer[5];
} 

//Function for reading the accelerometers
void getAccelerometerReadings(int accelResult[]) {
  byte buffer[6];
  readFrom(0x53,0x32,6,buffer);
  accelResult[0] = (((int)buffer[1]) << 8 ) | buffer[0]; //Yes, byte order different from gyros'
  accelResult[1] = (((int)buffer[3]) << 8 ) | buffer[2];
  accelResult[2] = (((int)buffer[5]) << 8 ) | buffer[4];
}

void setup() {
  Wire.begin();            //Open I2C communications as master
  Serial.begin(9600);    //Open serial communications to the PC to see what's happening

  writeTo(0x53,0x31,0x09); //Set accelerometer to 11bit, +/-4g
  writeTo(0x53,0x2D,0x08); //Set accelerometer to measure mode
  writeTo(0x68,0x16,0x1A); //Set gyro to +/-2000deg/sec and 98Hz low pass filter
  writeTo(0x68,0x15,0x09); //Set gyro to 100Hz sample rate
}

void loop() {
  getGyroscopeReadings(gyroResult);
  getAccelerometerReadings(accelResult);

  Serial.print(gyroResult[0]);
  Serial.print("\t");
  Serial.print(gyroResult[1]);
  Serial.print("\t"); 
  Serial.print(gyroResult[2]);
  Serial.print("\t\t");
  Serial.print(accelResult[0]);
  Serial.print("\t");
  Serial.print(accelResult[1]);
  Serial.print("\t");
  Serial.print(accelResult[2]);
  Serial.print("\n");

  delay(50);
}
```

any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The `writeTo` functions**

The accelerometer and gyro both have some memory inside that is used to store the configuration. The specific locations and values can be read from the datasheet, but for now I'll trust the comments. These writeTo functions seem to set the device modes and configure the scale used for the sensors.

Notice that they only happen once, right when the program starts. Maybe the devices have a way of storing persistent settings onboard, but setting them once at each startup is safe and easy.

**The Bitwise ops**

These don't set the number of bits we are reading *per se*, They reconstruct larger than 8-bit values. The I2C serial protocol is set up to use 8-bit data segments, so to send any value larger than 8-bits they must be broken down, sent, and then "stitched" back together in chucks.

`(((int)buffer[0]) << 8 ) | buffer[1];`

Whats happening here is that `buffer[0]` is converted to int (a 16 bit value), then shifted over by 8 bits. This means the 8 bits in the original `buffer[0]` are now located in the top 8-bits of the integer, and the lower 8 bits are zeros. Finally the lower 8 bits are set by the bitwise-or operator `|`, which will turn on any bits that were set in `buffer[1]` in the result. Since the bottom 8-bits were 0's from the shift, this just copies `buffer[1]` in exactly.

The net effect is a 16 bit value that contains the bits of both 8-bit buffer values and can be interpreted as a single number.