# How can Arduino know Wire.available() is true or false?

Tags: serial, i2c, hardware, wire-library, buffer

In this part of code

```
void readFrom(byte device, byte fromAddress, int num, byte result[]) {
  Wire.beginTransmission(device);
  Wire.write(fromAddress);
  Wire.endTransmission();
  Wire.requestFrom((int)device, num);
  int i = 0;
  while(Wire.available()) {
    result[i] = Wire.read();
    i++;
  }
}
```

### How can Arduino know that Wire.availble() is true or false?

I thought that when the microcontroller "reads" the value from the sensor, in pieces of 8 bits, he reads from 0 (n) to 5 (n+5) at the I2C address of the MPU-6050, and when he increments 6 it finds nothing, but this is my conclusion, i am not sure about it. 
[image]

I am studying how Serial.available [works](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/37038/serial-available-function-for-arduino) and how the circular buffer works for the data comunication, because available() [inherits from the Stream utility class.](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/WireAvailable)

The entire code is the following taken from  [this question](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/8738/understanding-digital-imu-6dof-sketch)

```
  #include <Wire.h> //The I2C library

int gyroResult[3], accelResult[3];

//Function for writing a byte to an address on an I2C device
void writeTo(byte device, byte toAddress, byte val) {
  Wire.beginTransmission(device);  
  Wire.write(toAddress);        
  Wire.write(val);        
  Wire.endTransmission();
}

//Function for reading num bytes from addresses on an I2C device
void readFrom(byte device, byte fromAddress, int num, byte result[]) {
  Wire.beginTransmission(device);
  Wire.write(fromAddress);
  Wire.endTransmission();
  Wire.requestFrom((int)device, num);
  int i = 0;
  while(Wire.available()) {
    result[i] = Wire.read();
    i++;
  }
}

//Function for reading the gyros.
void getGyroscopeReadings(int gyroResult[]) {
  byte buffer[6];
  readFrom(0x68,0x1D,6,buffer);
  gyroResult[0] = (((int)buffer[0]) << 8 ) | buffer[1]; //Combine two bytes into one int
  gyroResult[1] = (((int)buffer[2]) << 8 ) | buffer[3];
  gyroResult[2] = (((int)buffer[4]) << 8 ) | buffer[5];
} 

//Function for reading the accelerometers
void getAccelerometerReadings(int accelResult[]) {
  byte buffer[6];
  readFrom(0x53,0x32,6,buffer);
  accelResult[0] = (((int)buffer[1]) << 8 ) | buffer[0]; //Yes, byte order different from gyros'
  accelResult[1] = (((int)buffer[3]) << 8 ) | buffer[2];
  accelResult[2] = (((int)buffer[5]) << 8 ) | buffer[4];
}

void setup() {
  Wire.begin();            //Open I2C communications as master
  Serial.begin(9600);    //Open serial communications to the PC to see what's happening

  writeTo(0x53,0x31,0x09); //Set accelerometer to 11bit, +/-4g
  writeTo(0x53,0x2D,0x08); //Set accelerometer to measure mode
  writeTo(0x68,0x16,0x1A); //Set gyro to +/-2000deg/sec and 98Hz low pass filter
  writeTo(0x68,0x15,0x09); //Set gyro to 100Hz sample rate
}

void loop() {
  getGyroscopeReadings(gyroResult);
  getAccelerometerReadings(accelResult);

  Serial.print(gyroResult[0]);
  Serial.print("\t");
  Serial.print(gyroResult[1]);
  Serial.print("\t"); 
  Serial.print(gyroResult[2]);
  Serial.print("\t\t");
  Serial.print(accelResult[0]);
  Serial.print("\t");
  Serial.print(accelResult[1]);
  Serial.print("\t");
  Serial.print(accelResult[2]);
  Serial.print("\n");

  delay(50);
}
```

### Minor Question

I am trying to undestand the difference between the register and the device address, but i did find anything on my book. 
[image]

Comment: You've used lots of words, but I don't actually understand what it is you think you are asking.

Comment: Sorry, i think my bad english is  a problem to explain my question. The while statement end when `Wire.available()` is false. This happen when there is nothig to read (?). How can arduino know that there is nothing nothing more to be read? Thank you :)

Comment: Because the Wire library software coupled with the I2C hardware interface has determined that is the case? You should read the datasheet and the Wire library source code.

Comment: If you request 5 bytes you have 5 bytes in the buffer, and when you have read all 5 there will be nothing available.

Comment: Ok, i think, now is little bit clearer, i will read the [Wire library source code](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/tree/master/hardware/arduino/avr/libraries/Wire) . I have read the mpu6050 datasheet yet, your [blog post on buffer](https://hackingmajenkoblog.wordpress.com/2016/02/01/reading-serial-on-the-arduino/), but it was still not clear and hard for a self-taught like me :)

Comment: I2C is one of the harder protocols to understand. It has nothing in common (other than the fact that one bit follows another) with Serial, so reading Serial in the hope of understanding I2C is not going to help.

Comment: Ok so is very normal to have this difficulties :)

Comment: When the Wire.requestFrom is used, the receive buffer inside the Wire library is cleared and the received data is stored in that buffer. The Wire.available tells how many bytes are in that buffer. That means you start with a fresh cleared buffer every time before reading data from a sensor. The I2C only defines that the first byte is the address of the sensor. How the sensor selects its internal register or how it handles commands is up to the sensor. Often a byte is written to set the register-address inside the sensor and after that a number of data bytes is read from the sensor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is that the Arduino Wire library has an internal buffer, and it can bring in characters and have them sitting there ready for you to pick them up.

It can also sense a total disconnect because of the way it uses both data pins to establish communications.  It is more like a current loop than a simple one-is-transmit-and-the-other-is-receive.  If it disconnects the Arduino knows it is not available.

Kudos on going to the documentation, by the way.